# magento - documentation for public interface of magento core models

Tags: php, magento, documentation

Let's say I have this code:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
```

I would like to know what methods I can call on `$order` object. Is there any good online reference where I can find available methods? I am trying to write my own module (observer more precisely) and I need to access order object and for instance pull a user out of it. But I can't find any good docs (reference) so that I can achieve this goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this code

```
$class_name=get_class($order);
$methods =get_class_methods($class_name);
echo "Methods Available";
foreach($methods as $method)
{
    var_dump($method);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this php function

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(get_class_methods($order));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just located `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`. I guess the best is to just look at list of methods in doc string at the beginning.

Comment: yes but this class extends some other class and so on so it is best to use default php methods

Comment: On the other hand, with the php code there are some methods missing (magic ones I guess) like getCustomerId but they are documented in the code.